# Maven Integration for Android Development

Tags: android, maven, maven-plugin, android-maven-plugin, maven-ant-tasks

**How can we used Maven for android?**

I'm using Lint tool in android for programming error solution.

Is it Maven same as this tool or provide more features over android?

Because i'm using Maven tool in Java programming for different kinds of testing like integration testing unit testing with predefined test cases.

If Maven work same in android also, than provide me help to implement in my existing project. What basic steps needs to be done for integrate Maven in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following two links help you to start with Maven integration in android:

1. [m2eclipse-android-integration](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/)
2. [New Maven Android Plugin features](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/07/new-maven-android-plugin-features.html)

If you have any specific requirement or query than you can ask me.